# Is there a centralized schedule of data release dates for U.S. federal agencies?

Tags: usa, government, releasing-data, data.gov

Is there some centralized or streamlined source of data release schedules for major U.S. government agencies? Something that combines sources such as the [BLS Schedule of Data Release](http://www.bls.gov/lau/lausched.htm), [ACS Data Release Dates](http://www.census.gov/acs/www/data_documentation/data_main/) etc.

[Data.Gov](http://www.data.gov/metric/federalagency/datasetpublishedpermonth) tracks this type of thing retroactively and makes it easy to follow the newest releases, but I can't find a similar forward-looking record set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On [Data.gov](http://www.data.gov) we haven't looked at trying to aggregate a forward-looking schedule. In general we encourage agencies to release data as quickly as possible. Some data releases occur on a very regular basis, but there is often some fluctuation based on the internal approval processes.  I expect as agencies respond to the actions to comply with the new Open Data Executive Order http://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2013/05/09/executive-order-making-open-and-machine-readable-new-default-government- it will be easier to create such a list.